# Is it possible to populate a select list field from another grid field?

Tags: channel, fieldtype, fields, grid

I'm working on a project where the client wants to be able to upload new page background images and then select one for each page/section of the site.

A solution I thought might solve this would be to have a grid field allowing for the uploading of the images, say up to 10 rows. Then add in another select list field that is populated from the previous grid field. I could then take that selected value and change the background image via css.

As the grid field is quite new I'm not sure if this is possible?

Also, if there is a better way of solving this please advise too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use the standard file field and set up a folder for backgrounds? Your client can then either select an already-uploaded image from the list of files, or upload a new one. You can restrict this field to one folder so there's no room for confusion and have it as a field in your pages channel.

This way you don't have two separate strands to the workflow (upload in one place, then select somewhere else).

Or am I misunderstanding your needs?

Comment: Thanks Penzizzle, I feel a little bit daft now for over-thinking it. Should have thought of something simpler like this. Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using any FT  which can retrieve data by query (for example SELECT+). But will be needed to save entry first after upload images to get it in select field.

Other way is to create this field (simple select + little bit JS coding).

But take attention on **Penzizzle** advice - way which you choose is looks little bit unusual.

Comment: Thanks Max, you are right about Penzizle's idea, simpler is usually better.